# No /dev/dri after upgrading to 21.04

Tags: kernel, x11

Recently upgraded from 20.04 to 21.04, which installed kernel 5.11.  Now it fails to start X with correct screen dimensions, due I assume to this in Xorg log:

`[    23.307] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory`

If I boot the 5.4 kernel, everything works properly.

FWIW:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] (rev a1)

# lshw -C video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Further update: compared the dmesg outputs after booting each kernel.  The 5.11 one makes no mention of `nouveau`, where the 5.4 one is full of it.

Answer (score 0):

After days of fruitless searching, I decided to revert the system to its pre-upgrade state, using `Timeshift`. Disastrous; `Xorg` would not work at all. I thought, "Well, nothing to lose", so tried the upgrade from 20.04 to 21.04 again. This time everything worked afterwards! I can only assume that there was an error in the first upgrade attempt.

Comment: Spoke too soon!  After a rebuild of the V4L drivers, the problem was back.

Comment: Since then I have upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10, kernel 5.13, which fixed the problem. Then did the V4L rebuild, which brought the problem back again.  At least I know where to look, though I still can't figure out how the problem arises.  Any V4L experts out there?